# how to close this type of application? C# , Excel

Tags: c#, excel

I have an excel spreadsheet converter, the problem is that with each modified worksheet it forms an executable and does not close it, how do I close this process?

link:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMSRb.jpg

```
private void Convert_CSV_To_Excel()
{

    // Rename .csv To .xlsm
    System.IO.File.Move(File, File);

    var _app = new Excel.Application();
    var _workbooks = _app.Workbooks;

    _workbooks.OpenText(File,
                             DataType: Excel.XlTextParsingType.xlDelimited,
                             TextQualifier: Excel.XlTextQualifier.xlTextQualifierNone,
                             ConsecutiveDelimiter: true,
                             Semicolon: true);

    // Convert To Excle 97 / 2003
    _workbooks[1].SaveAs(File + "OK.xlsm", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled);
    _workbooks.Close(); 
}
```

Comment: Try `_app.Quit();` after closing the workbook.

Comment: @dvo well according to his Image the process that isn't shutting down is `wps.exe` and not `Excel.exe` so quitting the `Excel` application shouldn't make a difference - so I assume

Comment: @RandRandom Oh thanks. I didn't see the screenshot before.

Comment: I imagine the problem is outside of this particular function, and lies more in looped calls TO this function.  Somewhere outside of that, there's not any well-handled exits or cleanup happening.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of simple, and comprehensive, examples that should illustrate the purpose for you.

CREATE AN EXCEL FILE:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; 

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

            if (xlApp == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Excel is not properly installed!!");
                return;
            }


            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "ID";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Name";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 1] = "1";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 2] = "One";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 1] = "2";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 2] = "Two";



            xlWorkBook.SaveAs("d:\\csharp-Excel.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
            xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
            xlApp.Quit();

            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);

            MessageBox.Show("Excel file created , you can find the file d:\\csharp-Excel.xls");
        }

    }
}
```

http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-create-excel.htm

---

OPEN AN EXCEL FILE:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; 

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Excel.Application xlApp ;
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook ;
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet ;
            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("csharp.net-informations.xls", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            MessageBox.Show(xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1","A1").Value2.ToString());

            xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
            xlApp.Quit();

            releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
            releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
            releaseObject(xlApp);
        }

        private void releaseObject(object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
                obj = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                obj = null;
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to release the Object " + ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                GC.Collect();
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-open-excel.htm

---

READ AN EXCEL FILE:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; 

namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Excel.Application xlApp ;
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook ;
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet ;
            Excel.Range range ;

            string str;
            int rCnt ;
            int cCnt ;
            int rw = 0;
            int cl = 0;

            xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"d:\csharp-Excel.xls", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;
            rw = range.Rows.Count;
            cl = range.Columns.Count;


            for (rCnt = 1; rCnt  < = rw; rCnt++)
            {
                for (cCnt = 1; cCnt  < = cl; cCnt++)
                {
                    str = (string)(range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Excel.Range).Value2;
                    MessageBox.Show(str);
                }
            }

            xlWorkBook.Close(true, null, null);
            xlApp.Quit();

            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);

        }

    }
}
```

http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-read-excel.htm